# explode and process php dynamic arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that is built dynamically.
Here's the form input

```
echo'<input class="input stickyinput" type="number"  name="'.$pestname['scoutlogpestname'].'#'.$obj['card_id'].'" >
```

The `$pestname['scoutlogpestname']` can always be different. The `$obj['card_id']` can be any value from `1-50`. I placed the `#` in the name figuring I would need a delimiter to explode with.
The array that prints looks like this. Numbers for any values entered and blank for any not entered.

```
Array
(
    [Aphids#1] => 11
    [Thrips#1] => 5
    [White-Fly#1] => 7
    [Aphids#2] => 
    [Thrips#2] => 1
    [White-Fly#2] => 22
    [Aphids#3] => 4
    [Thrips#3] => 1
    [White-Fly#3] => 
    etc....... possibly to 50
)
```

Can somebody please give me some insight on how to execute the explode loop so I can process the `$pestname['scoutlogpestname']` and the `$obj['card_id']` values? Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lose that weird hash thing and just use array notation in your form fields. For example...

```
<input name="<?= htmlspecialchars($pestname['scoutlogpestname']) ?>[<?= $obj['card_id'] ?>]" ...
```

This will produce something like

```
<input name="Aphids[1]" ...
<input name="Aphids[2]" ...
```

When submitted, this will give you an array of arrays in the `$_POST` super global, eg

```
Array
(
    [Aphids] => Array
        (
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 
        )
)
```

You can then iterate each entry and value array, eg

```
foreach ($_POST as $pestname => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $card_id => $value) {
        // code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that nudge Phil. I just started finding the need for arrays and as usual the help here at Stack overflow gets me pointed in the correct direction. Your code shows me the values that I need. I should be able to process them now. Thanks for your help and thanks to all that replied. I changed my markup for the inputs.;)

Comment: I tied to add another array from a hidden input named $cardtype but it isn't doing what I thought it would. I tried a few variations. Am I close. foreach ($_POST as $pestname => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $cardtype => $card_type) {
 $card_type;

   }
 
 foreach ($values as $card_id => $pestcount) {
   
   $pestname;
     $card_id;
   $pestcount; }}

Comment: @Progrower Probably best to ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate all fields, then consider using a simple foreach and split the array keys based on "#":

```
// e.g. ['Aphids#1' => 11]
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    list($pest_name, $card_id) = explode('#', $key, 2);
}
```

The variables `$pest_name` and `$card_id` are assigned a value based on the results of the [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) operation.

See also: [`list`](http://php.net/list)

That said, storing values as part of a field name in that way is kind of clunky and it would be better to use an array syntax like Phil suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21975603/1338292).

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$array = array("Aphids#1" => 11,
    "Thrips#1" => 5,
    "White-Fly#1" => 7,
    "Aphids#2" => 5,
    "Thrips#2" => 1,
    "White-Fly#2" => 22,
    "Aphids#3" => 4,
    "Thrips#3" => 1);

$data = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $exploded = explode('#', $key);
    $obj = array(
        "pest_name" => $exploded[0],
        "card_id"   => $exploded[1],
        "value"     => $value
    );
    array_push($data, $obj);
}

echo "<pre>", print_r($data), "</pre>";
```

Will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pest_name] => Aphids
            [card_id] => 1
            [value] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pest_name] => Thrips
            [card_id] => 1
            [value] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pest_name] => White-Fly
            [card_id] => 1
            [value] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [pest_name] => Aphids
            [card_id] => 2
            [value] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [pest_name] => Thrips
            [card_id] => 2
            [value] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [pest_name] => White-Fly
            [card_id] => 2
            [value] => 22
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [pest_name] => Aphids
            [card_id] => 3
            [value] => 4
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [pest_name] => Thrips
            [card_id] => 3
            [value] => 1
        )

)
```