# Pass multiple dynamic arrays to php some hidden

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post

I received help already with a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975534/explode-and-process-php-dynamic-arrays) about posting an array.
 Now I'm trying to add more arrays to the loop
Here's the html

```
     <input class="input stickyinput" type="number"  name="pestcount[]">
     <input type="hidden" name="cardtype[]" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($obj['cardtype']) ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="cardid[]" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($obj['card_id']) ?>" />
     <input type="hidden" name="pestname[]" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($pestname['scoutlogpestname']) ?>" />
```

Here's the php

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['cardid']); $i++ ) {

    $card_id = $_POST['cardid'][$i];
    $card_type = $_POST['cardtype'][$i];
    $pest_count = $_POST['pestcount'][$i];
    $pest_name = $_POST['pestname'][$i];  

  $sql ="INSERT INTO scout_logpestnum (pest_name,pest_count,card_id,card_type)
        VALUES (:pest_name,:pest_count,:card_id,:card_type)"; 
  $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);     
$q->execute(array(':pest_name'=>$pest_name,':pest_count'=>$pest_count,':card_id'=>$card_id,':card_type'=>$card_type));

}
```

So what is the proper format for adding addition arrays from the form?. Thanks;)

Here's what my array looks like.

```
Array (
    [pestcount] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )
    [cardtype] => Array (
        [yellcard] =>
    )
    [cardid] => Array (
        [1] =>
    )
    [pestname] => Array (
        [Aphids] =>
        [Thrips] =>
        [White-Fly] =>
    )
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd like the `$_POST` data to look?

Comment: One example of a $cardtype **yellcard**. I'm in control of the $cardtype variable.

Comment: No, I mean like an example of how you want the `$_POST` array to look on form submission. Edit your question and add a sample.

Comment: I'm sorry Phil, I was actually saving to mysql. I should have posted that the first time. I updated my code.

Comment: The code above reflects my final working solution. I now have a better understanding of arrays. Thanks for all your help Phil.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *pests* and *cards* are separate collections, you can simply use a prefix to identify them in `$_POST` data. For example...

```
<input name="pests[<?= htmlspecialchars($pestname['scoutlogpestname']) ?>][<?= $obj['card_id'] ?>]" ...
```

and

```
<input name="cards[<?= htmlspecialchars($obj['cardtype']) ?>][<?= $obj['card_id'] ?>]" ...
```

This would produce HTML like

```
<input name="pests[Aphids][1]" ...

<input name="cards[yellcard][1]" ...
```

Then, in your form handler...

```
$pests = $_POST['pests'];
foreach ($pests as $pest_name => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $card_id => $pest_count) {
        echo $pest_name, $card_id, $pest_count;
    }
}

$cards = $_POST['cards'];
foreach ($cards as $card_type => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $card_id => $value) {
        echo $card_type, $card_id, $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I place my mysql insert in the loops now. The old version was obvious for me.

Comment: I worked on this last night and today and went a new direction. I posted the array print out.